# How to add email to Cognito access token?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognit, and when validating the access token I need to extract the email attribute to handle some migration cases between the app's database and Cognito.

but the issue is that I can't find the email in the token; instead, I get a username, which is a UUID.

is there any way to include the email to the access token (without making an extra call to pre-token-generation-lambda)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not currently supported. Your backend can however send the access token to the Cognito user info endpoint to get the email.

You can then produce a useful claims principal containing the email. Then cache the extra claims for subsequent backend requests. See [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts) for an example.

Comment: Yes, after some digging I'm switching to using the ID Token as it contains user info and claims.
Thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the ID Token instead of the access token as it has the required user attributes (email)